# MS Access Subforms - Allow only additions

Tags: ms-access, subforms

I am new to MS Access. I have two problems:

1. I have a main form where the user enters the vehicle number. In the subform below, the maintenance records of that vehicle is displayed. Now what I want is that no one should be able to make changes in the previous records and allow only additions of new record. **If a VB Code is required where should it be placed, in mainform or in subform**?
2. The Mileage value of a new record should always be greater than previous value, logical, right?  **Now how do I read the last mileage value so as to compare it with new value**?

Answer (score 2):

I would set the sub form allow edits = no.

I would then on the main form have a button to launch a another form that is based on the same table as the sub form.

The user thus can click on this button, add the record, and then when they close the record, you refresh the sub form to disaply that new record.

In other words, you quite much stating that existing reocrds in the sub form are ONLY for display – not to allow futher edits or changes.

So behind the button (you place it on the main form), you could have this code:

```
Dim f        As String
If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False ' force data save

f = "frmFoodAdd"

DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , , acFormAdd
Forms(f)!tblHotels_ID = me.id
DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , , , acDialog       ' change form to "wait" for user
Me.MySubForm.Requery
```

Of course in above, you change f = "you  form you created to allow adding one row"

tblHotels_ID = me.id

Above, change tblHotels_ID to the column used to link the child table back to the main form. Subforms "set" this value automatic, but launching a form separate DOES no

Comment: Thanx Albert, it helped. Great